# Using hashes in a chaining manner

Tags: perl

Using hashes in a chaining manner confuses me a lot. For instance, I read the following Perl codes, how to understand them piece by piece?

```
$model->{result}->{forcast}->[$index]->{label}  = 1;

$Neg{$examples->{result}->[$index]->{title}} = 1
```

In addition, why some items has $ , like $index; while others do not have, like label.

$index is wrapped in [ ]  while others are wrapped in { }, what are the differences here?

Is `$Neg{$examples->{result}->[$index]->{title}} = 1`  equivalent to `$Neg{$examples->{result}->[$index]->{title}} = 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider:

```
$model->{result}->{forcast}->[$index]->{label}  = 1;
```

`->[]` is used to dereference an array reference.
`->{}` is used to dereference a hash reference.

Let us scan it from the left:

- `$model` is a hash reference (due to it being used in the context: `$model->{}`)
- `result` is a hash key (as it does not have a `$` sigil prepended)
- `$model->{result}` is again a hash reference
- `$model->{result}->{forcast}` is an array reference (due to it being used in the context: `$model->{result}->{forcast}->[]`)
- `$index` is a variable set by the user that possibly contains the index of an array item
- `$model->{result}->{forcast}->[$index]` is a hash reference
- `label` is a hash key
- `$model->{result}->{forcast}->[$index]->{label}` sets `1` as the value for the hash key

Hash keys can be barewords, which will be automatically quoted. So, specifying the hash key as `result` or `'result'` are the same.

[`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) is the cookbook for data structures. [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) is very helpful in viewing such data structures.

Answer (score -4):

You shouldn't have plain-text hash keys like that without quotations. Say this:

```
$model->{'result'}->{'forcast'}->[$index]->{'label'} = 1
```

So model is a hashref, it has a key 'result' which is a hashref, which has a key 'forcast' (can't spell?) which is an arrayref, which at index `$index` has a hashref, which has a key 'label' which is being set to 1.

In the second one,  `%Neg` is a hash which has a key that is the 'title' element from the chain of nested hashes and arrays.

And as for your last question, yes they are because you wrote the same thing twice.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with leaving out the quotation marks for hash keys. As long as the key doesn't contain any whitespace it works fine.

Comment: unless you're using warnings, as is best practice. And if you aren't using warnings then you're a Bad Person.

Comment: There is no warning for using unquoted hash keys.

Comment: Unquoted identifiers as hash keys is perfectly fine. No strict errors. No warnings.

Comment: No, it is not perfectly fine.  Though it works and doesn't trigger a warning, the extra visual cue is well worth always including the quotes.

Comment: Personally I find the extra visual noise of quotes within hash keys to be distracting, but that's just MHO.